# correct implementation of plupdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

i´m implementing this upload library, maybe not much people use this, but maybe somebody can help me to figure how to solve this.

So i'm already uploading, the thing is that i want to implement the "uploader" objet, like

```
upload.bind();
```

i would like to know if anybody here can provide me links or maybe clear my idea.

thank you so much.

This is my code:

```
        uploader = $("#uploader").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        url: objMaterial.geturl(),
        urlstream_upload: true, //cambiar url en tiempo real
        multi_selection: multiSelection,
        unique_names: unicoNombre,
        // User can upload no more then 20 files in one go (sets multiple_queues to false)
        max_file_count: 1,
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        // Resize images on clientside if we can        
        filters: {
            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size: '50mb',
            // Specify what files to browse for
            mime_types: [
                {   
                    title: titulo, 
                    extensions: extensiones
                }
            ]
        },
        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,
        // Sort files
        sortable: true,
        // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
        dragdrop: true,
        // Views to activate
        views: {
            list: true,
            thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
            active: 'thumbs'
        },
        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '../../js/Moxie.swf',
        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '../../js/Moxie.xap'
    });
    //uploader = $("#uploader").plupload();
   uploader = $('#uploader').plupload();
   console.log(uploader);
    //uploader = $("#flash_uploader").pluploadQueue();

    uploader.bind('QueueChanged', function (up, files)
    {
        files_remaining = uploader.files.length;
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i want to answer this question, i found a solution.

so all these objects are events.

here you have a complete example of how to implement them.

```
uploader = $("#uploader").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5,html4',
        url: objMaterial.geturl(),
        // Maximum file size
        max_file_size: '50mb',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        max_file_count: 1,
        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            quality: 90,
            crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
        },
        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
            {title: "PDF", extensions: "PDF"}
        ],
        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,
        // Sort files
        sortable: true,
        // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
        dragdrop: true,
        // Views to activate
        views: {
            list: true,
            thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
            active: 'thumbs'
        },
        // Post init events, bound after the internal events
        init: {
            PostInit: function () {
                // Called after initialization is finished and internal event handlers bound
                log('[PostInit]');
                document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function () {
                    uploader.start();
                    return false;
                };
            },
            Browse: function (up) {
                                // Called when file picker is clicked                                       
                        },
                        Refresh: function (up) {
                                // Called when the position or dimensions of the picker change                                        
                        }, 
                        StateChanged: function (up) {
                                // Called when the state of the queue is changed                                        
                        }, 
                        QueueChanged: function (up) {
                                // Called when queue is changed by adding or removing files                                        
                        },
            OptionChanged: function (up, name, value, oldValue) {
                // Called when one of the configuration options is changed
            },
            BeforeUpload: function (up, file) {
                // Called right before the upload for a given file starts, can be used to cancel it if required
            },
                        UploadProgress: function (up, file) {
                                // Called while file is being uploaded                                        
                        },
            FileFiltered: function (up, file) {
                // Called when file successfully files all the filters                                        
            },
                        FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                                // Called when files are added to queue                                       
                                plupload.each(files, function (file) {                                                
                                });
                        },
                        FilesRemoved: function (up, files) {
                                // Called when files are removed from queue                                        
                                plupload.each(files, function (file) {                                                
                                });
                        }, 
                        FileUploaded: function (up, file, info) {
                                // Called when file has finished uploading
                jQueryMessage('El archivo se ha enviado exitosamente!', 1);                                        
                        }, 
                        ChunkUploaded: function (up, file, info) {
                                // Called when file chunk has finished uploading                                        
                        },
            UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
                // Called when all files are either uploaded or failed                                        
            },
            Destroy: function (up) {
                // Called when uploader is destroyed                                        
            },
                        Error: function (up, args) {
                                // Called when error occurs                                        
                        }
            },
        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap'
    });
```

i hope this can help you